# Only clearing messages younger than two weeks in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a command where my discord bot deletes a specified amount of text, the problem is that discord.js doesn't let you delete messsages older than 2 weeks, so if someone tries do delete for example 30 messages, and one of them is older than 2 weeks, it won't delete anything.

**Here's the code**

```
if (message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
    {
        if (args[0])
        {
            if (!isNaN(args[0]))
            {
                
                message.channel.bulkDelete(parseInt(args[0]) + 1).then(() => {
                message.channel.send(`**Deleted ${args[0]} messages**`)
                .then(message => {
                message.delete({ timeout: 2000 });
            });
            });
            }
            else 
            {
                message.reply("Please enter a valid number of messages to delete");
            }

        
        }
        else 
        {
            message.reply("*You didn't specify how many messages to delete.*");
        }

        
    }
    else 
    {
        message.reply("You can't use that");
    }
```

Is there any way to delete every message up until the ones that are older than two weeks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `filterOld` option for [TextChannel#bulkDelete()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete)

```js
const deleteTarget = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;

message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteTarget, {
   filterOld: true
}).then(messages => {
   const deletedResult = messages.size;

   // Compare deleteTarget and deletedResults as both return numbers
});
```

This will filter all messages that are older than 2 weeks leaving you with only the deletable messages, effectively bypassing errors.

Comment: Is there also a way to check if all specified number of messages have been deleted? Also thank you, your answer worked

Comment: Yes, `bulkDelete()` Returns a promise with a Collection of all deleted messages. You can get the `size` property to see how many messages ended up being deleted. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for answering, also I tried this but messages.size returns undefined. If I try to use Number(), it returns NaN

Comment: What returns when you log `messages`